# Make element unable to take focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Bottom line: I'd like to disable (with jQuery) certain elements from being able to take focus, as opposed to removing focus that's already applied. My issue may be IE-8 specific, so I'll consider IE-8 focussed solutions.

For example, I have a months-nav for which sometimes some months may not be valid selections, but I want to still present the month. Rather than cluttering my server-side logic and complicating my markup by switching to a span instead of a link for the invalid month, I'm just adding an "invalid" class to the li (link container)

```
<li class="valid">
    <a href="/subpubs/yearMonth/2011-1">Jan</a>
</li>       

<li class="invalid">
    <a href="/subpubs/yearMonth/2011-2">Feb</a>
</li>

[etc.]
```

This jQuery works to turn off the link and remove focus:

```
$('.invalid  > a').click(function () { $(this).blur(); return false; });
```

But in IE8 (though not IE7, don't know about IE9), the removal of focus by .blur() has enough of a delay that there's a visible blink (even with lonesomeday's solution). So I'd like another approach, or perhaps just a fix for IE8.

Is there away to just disable the link from being able to take focus at all?

Comment: Just from a usability standpoint, would it not be better to just hide the invalid link? Having an unclickable link is likely to lead to a lot of confusion in your visitors.

Comment: I agree with Rory above - in terms of making your semantic markup match your user experience, an unclickable link is a confusing paradigm to adopt. Plus, your link would still be clickable if JS was turned off, which presumably is not what you intended. Is it really so much hassle to do it on the server?

Comment: @Rory: I'd find having a list of say, 8 months with some missing in the middle is more confusing: "why are they missing? Is this a bug?" Also, some  months would shift in position (bad) as the content options change; say, when there are no articles for November, but then one's added. Rather, showing the unavailable month with a clear visual indicator that it is unavailable, un-clickable, (not *look* like a link) makes it clear that there is no content associated with that month. Making this work with link *tags* is just about finding a general solution that's easiest to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider switching all the invalid links to span markup using jQuery; this would be client-side rather than server-side. Is there a particular reason for removing the focus from these links? If they don't actually link to anything useful surely this is a case where server-side you *should* be replacing the links with just text?

Comment: I prefer a simple jQuery solution that doesn't require a markup change because replacing links with spans forces my markup, selectors and styles to be more complicated; I find myself making these kinds of nav-widgets all the time; and I strive to keep my server-side code as simple as well, so I'd really like to hone a very simple jQuery solution.

Answer (score 2):

The delay is probably in the construction of the jQuery object.  You could do this quicker if you call the native [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.blur) method:

```
$('.invalid  > a').click(function () { this.blur(); return false; });
```

Though I think you should probably do this with `focus` instead, so that users can't tab their way to your elements:

```
$('.invalid  > a').focus(function () { this.blur(); return false; });
```

---

The other option would be to replace all your "invalid" links with span elements using jQuery:

```
$('.invalid > a').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<span/>', {
        html: this.innerHTML,
        'class': 'disabled-link'
    });
});
```

Comment: It still blinks in IE8. Funny: I just noticed I was wrong about IE7 -- there's no blink there (well, at least IE8/compatibility-mode). I'll revise my question to detail this as an IE-8 specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

I once had the same problem, the best solution I found was to set the "tabindex" attr of the element to "-1". For example:

```
$('.invalid > a').attr('tabindex','-1');
```